# Why does reflection return two methods, when there is only one implementation?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, reflection

#### Suppose I have this code:

```
public interface Address {
    public int getNo();
}

public interface User<T extends Address> {
    public String getUsername();
    public T getAddress();    
}

public class AddressImpl implements Address {
    private int no;
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
}

public class UserImpl implements User<AddressImpl> {
    private String username;
    private AddressImpl addressImpl;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public AddressImpl getAddress() {
        return addressImpl;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressImpl addressImpl) {
        this.addressImpl = addressImpl;
    }
}
```

#### Running the code:

```
int getAddressMethodCount = 0;
for (Method method : UserImpl.class.getMethods()) {
    if (method.getName().startsWith("getAddress")) {
        getAddressMethodCount++;
    }
}
```

would yield 2 for `getAddressMethodCount` variable; why is this so?

Comment: i love SO. I am discovering things every single day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the way covariant return types are implemented. `javap -private` will show you more conveniently than reflection.

The subclass with have a synthetic bridge method that handles forwarding to the more specific method. As far the JVM is concerned methods have a name, a sequence of raw typed parameters and a raw type return. You can overload on return type in bytecode.

A `System.err.println(mehtod.getReturnType());` should give you different results for the two methods.

Comment: And which one is the one in my class?

Comment: They are both in your class. Interrogating the method for its return type will show that one method returns the Address while the other, the synthetic bridge that Tom mentions above, will return your AddressImpl type.

Comment: +1 Presumably calling [`isSynthetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isSynthetic\(\)) will return `true` on one `Method` and `false` on the other.

Comment: @PaulBellora Yeah, and `isBridge`. `javap -v` will show `ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC` flags.